# How do I prevent apps from automatically closing during updates?

Tags: application-autoupdate

I don't use my Android tablet very often, usually only once every week or two.  Therefore, when I do use it, it likes to pull down a bunch of updates each time.  That I don't mind.  What I do mind is that I'll be using apps and this updating is happening in the background, so all of a sudden my app goes away and I lose all my work.  Is there a way to tell the system, "hey, don't just blow away apps I have running to update them without me OKing it first"?

Comment: You can turn off Automatic Update in your play store settings

Answer (score 3):

There is no way you could stop from an app from getting terminated when getting updated.

**Because** when app is getting updated the apk inside the /data/app/nameoftheapp/base.apk gets updated and a .dex file must be made of the new base.apk

So the current process of the app is terminated and then daemon is invoked and it does it job of installing the app

Comment: Is there any way though of deferring the actual install operation (after download) until app is not running or user OKs though?

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch I'm afraid , No

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch You can use other store like aptoide